# Does Elasticsearch deletes all documents using delete_by_query, in any case, except query says match all?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

```
             {
              "query": {
                "terms": {
                  "MyId": [123 ]
                }
              }
            }
```

Is there, any chance, to delete all documents in elastic search index. by executing this query. Please suggest. Currently all indexed documents have been deleted. Which i could not able to trace/ find reason. your concern is much valuable at this moment. Thank you in advance.

my code :
   var deleteQueryResponse = ClientES.Client.LowLevel.DeleteByQuery(databaseName, datatableName,  postData);

where postData is above query.

I found 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/breaking_60_rest_changes.html 
Under Secton, Delete by query requires explicit query.

I am using elastic search version 5.5.1. Delete_by_query was working as expected. But suprisingly today, its deleting all the documents(which is the default case). how come this changes is effective today. I need reason.

Comment: Which version of ES are you running and how did you execute the delete by query?

Comment: version elasticsearch5.5.1 , using C#  Elasticsearch.net function.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Dear Val, i have update question. could i now the reason why it is effective now but not previously.

Comment: What does your mapping look like?  What are example documents that are deleted, that you didn't expect to be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch query built using c# string, was incorrect JSON. But _delete_by_query didn't throw any exception instead by default it deleted all the records.

I found https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/breaking_60_rest_changes.html Under Secton, Delete by query requires explicit query.